# Application that provides local and remote access to data

Tags: java, jsp, architecture, gwt

I need to develop an application with following features and want to
understand if GWT can be used to develop this application or is it the
right technology to use ?

1) Backend is in Java and uses MySQL
2) Desktop based UI to create some datafiles and data will be stored
in MySQL DB. This app will generate the data.
3) A desktop based application using which users can get access to
that database on a CD. This app will provide access to data locally
stored on a CD.
4) A web interface using which users can get access to the database
remotely. This app will provide remote access to data.

For local access also, we have the flexibility to install and run the
web server.

Should I use GWT for the UI part or should I use some thing else ? I
would like to provide common UI, look & feel for local and remote
access to data.

Please advice.

Thanks,
Deep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can run the web server also locally, I don't see a problem to re-use the same GWT app for both use cases.

It would be harder if your users must communicate with both the remote and local server from the same browser window/tab, at the same time. That can only be done with [JSONP](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/Xsite.html), which is possible with GWT, but it's not as nice as [GWTRPC](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC.html).